# Select query in relational two table mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

```
+--------------------------------------------+
|             category_table                 |
+----+--------------------+------------------+
+----+--------------------+------------------+
| id | cat_title          | parent           |
+----+--------------------+------------------+
|  1 | cat1               | 0                |
|  2 | cat2               | 1                |
|  3 | cat3               | 1                |
|  4 | cat4               | 2                |
|  5 | cat5               | 2                |
|  6 | cat6               | 2                |
+----+--------------------+------------------+


+---------------------------------------------------------------+
|                       content_table                           |
+----+--------------------+-------------------------------------+
+----+--------------------+------------------+------------------+
| id | title              | category         | content          |
+----+--------------------+------------------+------------------+
|  1 | title1             | 1                | test1            |
|  2 | title2             | 1                | test2            |
|  3 | title3             | 2                | test3            |
|  4 | title4             | 3                | test4            |
|  5 | title5             | 1                | test5            |
|  6 | title6             | 3                | test6            |
|  7 | title7             | 4                | test7            |
|  8 | title8             | 5                | test8            |
|  9 | title9             | 5                | test9            |
| 10 | title10            | 4                | test10           |
| 11 | title11            | 6                | test11           |
+----+--------------------+------------------+------------------+
```

Hi,

Assume that parent column 0 means "it is a main category" in category table, others are subcategory of other categories. I want to select all contents which are the child of cat1 and cat1's subcategories.

Comment: Can you also add expected result?

Comment: all content table is the result of this query because all of this rows are the child of cat1

Comment: No simple way to do this with that database design in MySQL. It requires a recursive query / recursively calling queries, unless you only want to cope with a fixed and limited number of levels of parent / child relationship. Possible you could hide these multiple queries in a procedure. However Google for the nested set model.

Comment: As a note, I'd use `NULL` to define the top level category.. that way you can still set up a proper foreign key relationship on the table.

Comment: If you have a chance to add a new column, you can add a "top" column to category_table. When you insert a category data specify the "top category id" as a top category id. With that structure you can query your need.

Comment: What is the depth of your categories? Will there be only 2 levels or more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this Query

```
select * from content_table where category IN (select id from category_table where parent IN 
(select id from category_table where cat_title = 'cat1'))
```

Comment: what is the result for this part - select id from category_table where parent IN 
(select id from category_table where cat_title = 'cat1')

Comment: Thank you its working :) but not working for unlimited sub category. how can i do it?

Comment: Use "where parent = 0" instead of "where cat_title = 'cat1'".